# Scaling atomic units with energy

Tags: units

In [Hartree atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units), $e = m_e = k_e = \hbar = 1$, and
\begin{align}
1&\mbox{ a.u. of energy is }E=\frac{m_ee^4}{(4\pi\varepsilon_0 \hbar)^2}=27.21\mbox{ eV.} \\ 
1&\mbox{ a.u. of time is }\frac{\hbar}{E}=2.419 \times 10^{-17}\mbox{ s} \\
1&\mbox{ a.u. of temperature is }\frac{E}{k_B}=3.16 \times 10^5\ \mbox{K} \\
1&\mbox{ a.u. of magnetic field is }\frac{\hbar}{ea_0^2}=2.35 \times 10^5\ \mbox{T}
\end{align}

However, if I wanted to re-scale the whole system so that $1$ unit of energy is $1\ \mbox{eV}$, how would I re-scale the other quantities to this new energy? Would I multiply time by 1/27.21 and temperature by 27.21? But then what about the magnetic field, which does not explicitly have an energy dependence?

Comment: It's arbitrary. You could re-scale just the energy if you want, keeping everything else fixed. Or anything else you like.

Comment: Reading "Babel of Units. The Evolution of Units Systems in Classical Electromagnetism" might assist. https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01951

Comment: @Chris, I don't see how you can keep everything else fixed. If you created a new set of units that also had $m_e=e=k_e=\hbar=1$, but instead had 1 unit of energy = 1 eV, then wouldn't the system be inconsistent if you still had 1 unit of time = 2.419*10^(-17) s? After all, there are many equations in which energy and time must multiply together. It seems to me that all other quantities must co-scale if you scale a single quantity. I don't understand how you can independently re-scale every quantity and still have a coherent unit system.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "everything else," I meant the four quantities you listed. I realise now that that wasn't remotely clear. Anyway, the main point is that there's not one way, but many different ways you can scale all of the different quantities.